# Is the singleton approach recommended for Azure SQL DB?

Tags: c#, azure, design-patterns, azure-sql-database, singleton

We are Azure SQL DB.

Right now we are creating, open & close connection for every incoming request. Like below

```
  on Startup.cs

            builder.Services.*AddScoped*<IDbConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection(""));
            builder.Services.*AddScoped*<Func<IDbConnection>>(svc => () => svc.GetRequiredService<IDbConnection>());


 on clientimpl.cs
       private readonly Func<IDbConnection> _connectionFactory;
       using (var connection = _connectionFactory())
            {
                //check status before open
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

             finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Instead of above approach,

Thought of creating the singleton sql conn objection and reusing the same instance through out the application lifetime rather creating, open & close connection for each & every request.

Is the singleton approach recommended for Azure SQL DB?
Are there any considerations?

Question:
builder.Services.AddScoped(_ => new SqlConnection("")); recommeded than builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => new SqlConnection("")); ??

Comment: Azure will cut inactive connections after a period of time. If you leave the connection open and nothing happens for a non-long period of time, your application's connection won't work any more either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't!

The connections are in a connection pool where they are being handled efficiently. They are not created and disposed, but given back to the pool.
Also using a singleton for the connection could lead to it being used concurrently in multiple places. That will lead to problems.

Your pattern is the correct pattern.

Comment: builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection("")); 
 recommeded than     builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDbConnection>(_ => new SqlConnection(""));

Comment: new SqlConnection("") ends up creating connection pool rather than single connection instance?

Comment: I wouldn't use any of them. You prevent yourself from utilizing the `using`  pattern. Instead inject a connection factory.

Comment: can you help me by pointing to any reference link for rightly implemented 'using' pattern & connection factory injection ?

Comment: I suppose your googling is a good as mine. But here's an example: https://blog.bitscry.com/2020/06/01/creating-a-dbconnectionfactory/. It's for multiple providers'

Comment: @ Palle Due, out of curiosity, to connect Azure SQL instance if singleton instance is not recommended way then why singleton instance is recommended for connection to Azure storage queue or event hub or cosmos db etc..?